# Is there any way to prevent opening of excel file when opened by other user?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've created an excel spreadsheet on a network drive. The problem is that users open it concurrently, then save their edited version to the desktop.

This means we either lose the edits of the person locking the file or lose the edits of the person stupid enough to write to the read-only version.

Is there any way to stop Windows offering to open the file in read-only mode?

Thanks in advance

Comment: FWIW, this is why there's a push for Office 365, Google Docs, and other collaborative software. You may be trying to solve this age-old problem the wrong way.

Comment: No, that's not possible. Your best way to go is educate the endusers...

Comment: this might be a bad idea, but how about a macro on open to change the password 'to open', to something random, then changing it on close, back to the original. As a safeguard you could write the new random password to a txt file elsewhere also so if you had a failure to save back to the original password, you would have a way to still get into it. This would only make it extremely inconvenient to bother trying to circumvent